# Trailblazer cells in the Rails console

Tags: cells, trailblazer

How can I work with a Trailblazer cell in the Rails console?

The **concept** helper doesn't work

```
irb(main):002:0> c = concept(Resource::Cell, l)
NoMethodError: undefined method `concept' for main:Object
Did you mean?  concern
               context
    from (irb):2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

concept() & cell() are Controller helpers, meaning they wouldn't work in console if the controller is not loaded. But you don't need them !

The easiest way to play with cell is just to invoke them like . you would with any other  ruby object.

**Cell**

```
# concepts/song/cell/cell.rb
module Song::Cell
  class Index < Trailblazer::Cell
    def show
      render
    end
  end

  class Show < Trailblazer::Cell
    def show
      render
    end
  end
end
```

**View**

```
%h1
  Song#show
%p
  Find me in app/concepts/song/view/show.haml
```

**Console**

```
# Any of the following calls - they are all equivalent pretty much
# The spit html output of the cell
Song::Cell::Show.(Song.last).()
Song::Cell::Show.(Song.last).render
Song::Cell::Show.(Song.last).(:show)
```